# Programatically check if a date-period has expired and possibly add new row to a table, daily

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table, named `ReportingPeriods`, that I want to be populated entirely automatically.  In another table, there are attributes `CreationDate` and `ReportingPeriodLength` which together will determine the the results of this row.  Upon adding a row for this table, we will add a row in `ReportingPeriods` with the first `StartDate` as the creation date and `EndDate` as `ReportingPeriodLength` days after startDate.

So far, this is simple.  However, I wish to check (daily) whether this period has expired.  And if it has, I want to start a new row, beginning the day after the `EndDate` and extending, once again, for `ReportingPeriodLength` days.

Is this possible to accomplish without manually checking and adding a new row?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call a stored procedure from a database job that is run each day.  within this procedure, do your check and insert if necessary.

Comment: Indeed, this is the route I was thinking.  However, how do you get this to run each day?

Comment: Look at SQl Server Jobs.  Under SQL Server Agent.  It is basically a scheduling utility.

Comment: when you set up a job you can set up a schedule, just select daily at a certain time (probably in the early AM)

Comment: by letting the DB do the scheduling and running the task, you get job history and error logging, no need to worry about other system outages (web server, network, etc.)  If the DB is running your job will run.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Scheduled Tasks is an appropriate tool for this.

You can write a simple script or a C# console application that calls a stored procedure in your database.  Add that executable as the command for a new scheduled task and pick an appropriate time.